# Mystery function: TotalResult()

Tags: php, excel

I'm editing some code produced by another developer. Within that code is a functon TotalResult() I think this is some kind of excel function as I'm pretty sure it's calling the data from an xls file. I've tried googling it in many different ways and I can't find a thing!

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction? I Need to know what its doing so I can locate some data.

Thanks :)

---

Scratch that - found it!

Comment: post function and elaborate what you're expecting.

Comment: It sounds like she doesn't even know where the function is defined. OP, try doing a grep on the codebase for `function TotalResult`

Answer (score 0):

Found the function hidden in the code, I had done a find in files and it didnt't make an appearance - a bit more of a dig and I stumbled accross it.

Even found the xls reference too! phew!

Comment: For the future, if you're using a good IDE, you should be able to right or ctrl click on a function and jump to it's definition. Check out PHP Storm.